# NSXMLParser error code 4 (Document is empty) and (parser: didStartElement: namespaceURI: qualifiedName: attributes: ) is not being called

Tags: ios, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse a list of Projects info from an xml file from a web api. The beginning of the file looks like:

```
<ArrayOfProject xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
<Project>
 <ExpectedEnergizingDate>2016-10-30T00:00:00</ExpectedEnergizingDate>
 <PlannedDate>2017-04-02T00:00:00</PlannedDate>
 <ProjectID>1-1432063</ProjectID>
 <ProjectName>
  Construction of Industrial7 SS in Jeddah and Connection With Network
 </ProjectName>
</Project>
<Project>
 <ExpectedEnergizingDate>2017-03-13T00:00:00</ExpectedEnergizingDate>
 <PlannedDate>2017-04-01T00:00:00</PlannedDate>
 <ProjectID>1-1432073</ProjectID>
 <ProjectName>
  Construction of Haram Road SS in Makkah Almukrmah and Connection With Network
 </ProjectName>
</Project>
```

These are my initWithData and main method of the parser delegate:

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)parseData
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        projectsData = [parseData copy];

        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
        [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];

    }
    return self;
}

// the main function for this NSOperation, to start the parsing
- (void)main
{
    self.currentParseBatch = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.currentParsedCharacterData = [NSMutableString string];

    //Printing the response
    NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:self.projectsData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",strData);
    //END

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:self.projectsData];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];

    self.currentParseBatch = nil;
    self.currentProjectObject = nil;
    self.currentParsedCharacterData = nil;
}
```

The problem is: although I'm sure I receive a response and the `self.projectsData` has information that I can `NSLog`, the parser however gives the Error Code 4 `Document is empty` without even calling the method `parser: didStartElement: namespaceURI: qualifiedName: attributes:`

Answer (score 0):

I found out he problem is that the http request response isn't an XML but JSON although the browser showing it as XML.